# jQuery AJAX $.ajax and $.get not alerting on either success or failure conditions

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, get

I've been trying out some jQuery AJAX with my loadTable.php file, which echoes a JSON output. However, I can't seem to get $.ajax or $.get to work. The following code doesn't alert anything at all, even when I put alert functions in both success and failure conditions. Obviously this isn't the final functionality, but even with this simple alert function it doesn't work. What am I doing wrong?

```
$('#tableLoad').click(function () {
  $('#sortable tbody').html('');

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'loadTable.php',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: data,
    success: function (data) {
      alert('Success!');
    },
    failure: function () {
      alert('Something went wrong!');
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: look at the documentation - failure doesn't exist as an event http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `error`, `failure` is not a valid option, see [`$.ajax`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/).

```
error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert('Something went wrong!');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you are using jQuery >=1.5 $.ajax returns a promise, as does any deferred object. This means you can chain your success or error functions onto the end of the ajax call.

They are, however, referred to as done and fail rather than success or error. In the below example "always" does exactly what it says and is called regardless of success or failure.

```
$.ajax( "example.php" )
   .done(function() {
     alert( "success" );
   })
   .fail(function() {
     alert( "error" );
   })
   .always(function() {
     alert( "complete" );
   });
```